RealityView change mesh of an entity that doesn't have ModelComponent
Is it possible to change the corner radius of a VideoPlayerComponent entity? Apparently its mesh is auto generated, the entity doesn't have a ModelComponent.
var body: some View {
  RealityView { content in 
    let entity = Entity()
    let player = AVPlayer()
    entity.components[VideoPlayerComponent.self] = .init(avPlayer: player)
    content.add(entity)
  }
}

Reference: WWDC23 Enhance your spatial computing app with RealityKit.

Controlling corner radii when using VideoPlayerComponent
The unpleasant thing about your example, is that by design of visionOS API, neither ModelComponent nor VideoPlayerComponent are exposed in the components' collection. In other words, you don't have access to either of these two components yet (I hope that RealityKit team will change this in the future). However, there is a solution (read further).

▿ 'video' : Entity
  ⟐ SynchronizationComponent
  ⟐ Transform


struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            let videoEntity = self.makeVideoEntity()
            videoEntity.name = "video"
            content.add(videoEntity)
            
            print(videoEntity)
        }
    }
    func makeVideoEntity() -> Entity {
        let entity = Entity()
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: Bundle.main.url(forResource: "video",
                                                  withExtension: "mov")!)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        let avp = AVPlayer()
        entity.components[VideoPlayerComponent.self] = .init(avPlayer: avp)
        entity.scale /= 2.5
        avp.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
        avp.play()
        return entity
    }
}

Solution
To create a video plane with nice corners' radii you need a premultiplied alpha channel (i.e. RGBA video) that controls transparency. For that use Apple Motion or Adobe After Effects software (you need to apply a mask with rounded corners to your video). The video resolution must be not lower than 1920x1080.
Once the mask is ready, export your video as Apple ProRes 4444 with alpha (use sRGB color space). Then open QuickTime Player and choose File –> Export As –> 1080p... You'll see a dialog in which you'll need to select:

You will not be able to see these settings if your video resolution is less than FullHD.
As a result, you will get a four-channel HEVC-with-Alpha file, which is significantly smaller than ProRes 4x4, and which is ready for use in visionOS.

Despite the fact that this is not the easiest way to round corners for a video (many developers would suggest just creating a plane primitive with a non-zero cornerRadius parameter), this approach has undeniable advantages:

you can round not all corners, but only 2 diagonally
you can make stylish torn edges on the mask
you can animate a mask


I feel this is an overkill for what it's worth. An alternative is just to create the mesh yourself and use video material: let entity = Entity() entity.components[ModelComponent.self] = .init(mesh: .generatePlane(width: 1, depth: 1, cornerRadius: 0.1), materials: [VideoMaterial(avPlayer: player)])

Yes, it is more labor-intensive than creating a RealityKit plane primitive. But we are discussing here how to do this based on VideoPlayerComponent. Your question excludes the use of ModelComponent. I've answered )))
